# Может ли быть блок полем класса?

Tags: objective-c

Знаю, что в objective-c начиная с версии 2.0 можно использовать блоки (замыкания, closures). Попыталась объявить один из полей с типом closure и ничего не вышло - ошибка. Можно ли сделать блок филдом класса или здесь неправильный синтаксис?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SomeItem.h"

@interface SomeController : UITableViewController {
@protected
    (BOOL(^)(SomeItem* item)) canApplyClosure;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
// Можно определить собственный тип (1)  
typedef BOOL (^canApplyClosureSecond)(NSObject *object);

@interface MyObject : NSObject {  
@private  
    // А можно писать вот так  
    BOOL (^canApplyClosure)(NSObject *object);  
    // (1)  
    canApplyClosureSecond anotherBlock;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
@interface SomeController : UITableViewController {
@protected
    BOOL(^canApplyClosure)(SomeItem*);
}
@end
```

хотя лучше конечно так:

```
@interface SomeController
@property (nonatomic, copy) BOOL(^canApplyClosure)(SomeItem*)
@end
```